# Event triggering without a direct connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

In my ASP.NET app I have a control in the master page that raises an event `Foo` on certain occasions / interactions.

I also have a couple of pages that have another control that must re-bind itself when this event is fired.

Unfortunately the only way I can see them communicating between each other is by creating a long event chain (deriving a new MasterPage `MasterPageSuperDuper`, attaching an event handler to `Foo`'s event in the user control, and then referring to this event in the masterpage from the control present in a couple of pages - basically using the masterpage as a control center).

Is it possible to raise an event the page control can see without getting the masterpage involved?

Comment: try Control.RaiseBubbleEvent Method

Comment: Are you using update panels or just regular postbacks?

Comment: @BiffMaGriff - regular postbacks

Comment: Why don't you capture the event on your master and just iterate through it's controls? Edit: Hmm, maybe just in your control. Something like `foreach(MyControl c in this.Parent.Parent.Controls) c.bind();`

Comment: I cant reference the control on /abcde.aspx from the masterpage without some poor coding practises (FindControl()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go.

Create an Interface, put in app_code folder

```
public interface IBinder
{
    void Bind();
}
```

PageControl Implement Interface

```
public partial class WebUserControl2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IBinder
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Bind()
    {
    }
}
```

In your Control on the masterpage

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void butRaiseEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckSub(this.Parent.Parent.Controls);
    }

    private void CheckSub(ControlCollection cc)
    {
        foreach (Control c in cc)
        {
            if (c is IBinder)
                ((IBinder)c).Bind();
            else
                CheckSub(c.Controls);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The controls on the page have no clue who the other "children" are, so you can't automagically have them say "look, there is another control on this page. How are you doing other control?" without doing some work, normally through the parent container.

There are mechanisms you can use to kludge things, but you still have to get the events through a common "container" like the page or master page.

I am curious why you are raising events in your master page that require such intricate control at the child level. I would imagine there is a more elegant architectural solution.

Comment: The event chain has to run through the masterpage at current, there is no other way for the control in the masterpage to communicate to /abcdef.aspx to know otherwise.